# Prevent duplicate login with FOSUserBundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle

Our application is using **Symfony 2.0** and **MongoDB** with **FOSUserBundle** for user management.

**Client wants to prevent login with the same username from different device at the same time in their application.**

Our idea is to invalidate/delete all other sessions for the same user when the successful login occurs.

The problem is, that we cannot save session in DB, because Mongo Session handler was added later in the version 2.1.

The only solution we come up with is to iterate over the session files saved in file-system and check if the username of the user is saved in that file. If that is true, we just delete the file and login session on other locations are terminated. Of course we have to check that we don't delete the current session also.

Does anyone have a better idea how the problem could be solved?
If not, are there any hidden traps that we should know about?

Comment: Is there any issue with multiple login?

Comment: yes, the client wants to prevent sharing usernames between application users.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615363

Comment: its similar, but not the same. in that question they want to disallow  login of already logined user. In my case, I want to logout all users on login of the same user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an IP address column to the user entity that stores the current user's IP upon login.  On each page load (via an event listener), you could check the IP stored in the DB against the IP of the person requesting the page.  If the IP in the DB doesn't match the current user's IP (someone logged in from another location), log them out.

To take it a step further, via ajax, you could make a call to the server every X seconds that performs the same type of check, and do a redirect to log the user out if the ajax request returns a bad match.

Comment: Good idea. The session ID could also be used instead of the IP adress to achieve this function

Comment: it works like a charm. Used Mike's proposal, but with SessID instead of IP. Thx.

Comment: [Here's a link to my SO question/answer that addresses this solution with more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368713/prevent-simultaneous-user-sessions-in-symfony2/25388011#25388011)

Comment: IP is not a good solution because people in the same company could all have the same external IP